# How to check if one row is existing in a big data frame with different column length in r

Tags: r, match

I am trying to match if one row of value matchs in a data frame but `%in%` function seems not working correctly.

Here is an example:

```
> c
  a b
1 1 2

> d
  a b
1 1 1

> g
  a b f
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
```

Is there anyway I can check if a row exists in a large data frame `g` and print out `TRUE` for row `d` and `FALSE` for row `c`?

For your convenience, here is the sample data code:

```
a<-1;b<-2;c<-data.frame(a,b);a<-1;b<-1;d<-data.frame(a,b);a<-c(1,2,3);b<-c(1,2,3);f<-c(1,2,3);g<-data.frame(a,b,f)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `paste` the rows and then do `%in%`

```
do.call(paste, c) %in% do.call(paste, g[names(c)])
#[1] FALSE

do.call(paste, d) %in% do.call(paste, g[names(d)])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and it works perfectly, could you explain a little bit about the methodology? I though data with different length of columns are not comparable.

Comment: @Y.Z.  As per your post, the comparison is between an one row dataset with a multi row dataset i'e', 'g'.  The `do.call(paste`, paste the elements of each row together to create a string `do.call(paste, c)
#[1] "1 2"` and compare with similar strings in 'g' i.e. `do.call(paste, g[names(c)])
#[1] "1 1" "2 2" "3 3"`.  Now, we are comparing two vectors instead of `data.frame.  and as there is a single element on the lhs of `%in%`, it returns FALSE/TRUE based on if the element is not present/present in the other vector

Comment: How do I know if `a`, `b` from `d` is not comparing with `b`, `f` instead of `a`, `b` columns from `g` since their values are all the same?

Comment: @Y.Z.  Assuming that 'g' include columns from 'c' and 'c', we subset the 'g' dataset with `g[names(d)]` or `g[names(c)]`

Comment: Is your function automatically subset the extra columns from the big data frame or I need to do the subset function before that?

Comment: @Y.Z.  The `names(c)` or `names(d)` are the column names of 'c' and 'd'.  So, if we assume that these columns exist in 'g', we are subsetting the 'g' dataset with only those columns.  I guess you got my point, right

Comment: Everything makes sense now. Thank you again for your answer and your explanation afterwards!

Answer (score 2):

We can create a function, using the `intersect` from the `dplyr` package to compare data frames.

In this example, `dt2` is the data frame with more columns than `dt1`.

```
is.match <- function(dt1, dt2){
  temp <- dplyr::intersect(dt1, dt2[, names(dt1)])
  if (nrow(temp) == 0){
    return(FALSE)
  } else {
    return(TRUE)
  }
}

is.match(c, g)
# [1] FALSE
is.match(d, g)
# [1] TRUE
```